# can local variables inside a sealed object pass information to global variables?

Tags: javascript, strict-mode

Not sure if I'm wording this correctly but can local variables inside a sealed object pass information to global variables?

Comment: What do you mean by 'pass information'?  Do you mean to ask if they can modify or set values to global variables?

Comment: Yes. lets say var hello = 2 is the global variable and there's a function within a sealed object. And inside the function is var hello = 3. Should it update the global variable to 3?

Comment: correction. within the function is hello = 3 not var hello = 3.

Comment: What's a "sealed object" ? You can easily write a piece of code that tests it!

Comment: Sorry I'm still very new to this. This page will explain it better. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they can:

```
var hello = 0, obj;

obj = {
  foo: function () {
    hello = 3;
  }
};

Object.seal(obj);

console.log(hello); //logs 0
obj.foo();
console.log(hello); //logs 3
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btipling/96s4emer/).